# Open folder using Powershell command line doesn't work

Tags: powershell

**If I have the command line below, on Powershell, is working, it open the disk C:**

```
Invoke-Item C:
```

**But if I try to open a directory**

```
Invoke-Item j:\DE SCANAT\Home
```

**I get this error:**

```
Invoke-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'SCANAT'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Item j:\DE SCANAT\Home
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeItemCommand
```

Comment: Please use double quotes because of the blank in the path: `Invoke-Item "j:\DE SCANAT\Home"`

Answer (score 2):

There's a `blank` in the path. So it's interpreted as new parameter.
This can be solved by using double quotes for the path:

`Invoke-Item "j:\DE SCANAT\Home"`

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to acces a directory with Powershell use this command:**

```
cd 'j:\DE SCANAT\socc\Haitov, Nikolai\'
```

**Alternatively, you can use backslashes ` to escape the spaces:**

```
Invoke-Item j:\DE` SCANAT\Home
```

**Use command "explorer" or "cd" to enter in a directory:**

```
explorer.exe 'j:\DE SCANAT\socc\Haitov, Nikolai\Aventuri in padure'
```

**OR**

```
cd 'j:\DE SCANAT\socc\Haitov, Nikolai\Aventuri in padure'
```